# onReceive function causing URL in custom textview to blink?

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, swiftui, nsattributedstring

I have a timer set up that is called once every few seconds:

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

I have a .onReceive() function that its called whenever the timer hits the 5 second mark:

```
    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        MapView().onReceive(self.timer) { input in
            self.database.fetchItems()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for annotation in self.annotations.annos {
                    if annotation !== self.selectedAnnotation {
                        self.map.removeAnnotation(annotation)
                    }
                }
                for item in self.database.items {
                    
                    self.annotations.addNextAnnotation(ID: item.id)
                    
                    var int = 0
                    for annotation in self.annotations.annos {
                        if annotation.title! == "\(item.id)" {
                            self.annotationsVM.annos.remove(at: int)
                            break
                        }
                        int = int + 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        VStack {
            TextView(text: NSAttributedString(string: "testing this thing https://google.com and putting some text after"), mapStyle: "light")
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have a custom text view that I implemented and I add an underline to links that are detected in the text itself:

```
class MyTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    print(URL)
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
    return false
}
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
var text: NSAttributedString
var mapStyle: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyTextView {
    let view = MyTextView()
    view.dataDetectorTypes = .link
    view.isEditable        = false
    view.isSelectable      = true
    view.delegate          = view
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    if self.mapStyle == "dark" {
        view.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    } else {
        view.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    }
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyTextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.attributedText = text
    if self.mapStyle == "dark" {
        uiView.textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        uiView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    uiView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)
}
}
```

The issue I'm running into, is in the textview that I am rendering, it detects the link correctly and makes it clickable and all that good stuff but for some reason, the clickable link blinks whenever the onReceive function is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example to debug.

Comment: @Asperi I updated it with more or less a reproducible example, I left out the MapView file because that's a super common file and I'm sure you know what it looks like--Also obviously I can't put in all the files that link the front end to the database so I did what I could with making the onReceive function comprehensible.